# javascript .className not replacing previous style

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i add .className to change a style of something with or without an event it's not replacing previous styles such as color, it will add new style properties but not replace old ones with new ones.

```
var loadbutton = document.getElementById('initialbutton');
var loadtext = document.getElementById('altertext');

var mainfunc = function(){
    loadtext.className = "changedtext";
}

loadbutton.addEventListener("click",mainfunc,false)



#altertext {
    color:#F00;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.changedtext {
    color:#0F0;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

first ID is the original style and the class is the class i want to apply. So onclick it will apply the changed 'font-style' and changed 'font-size' but the color remains red. I want it to replace the red with the new color

Answer (score 4):

It's actually a right behaviour. It's all about CSS specificity. The styles in your selector containing `id` are with higher specificity then those in the selector containing `class`. I'll suggest to put the first styles in a `class`, not attaching them to the `id`:

```
.altertext {
    color:#F00;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Or simply define the things like that

```
#altertext .changedtext {
    color:#0F0;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

Using the second approach your specificity is 0110 (#altertext .changedtext), which is higher then 0100 (#altertext).

Answer (score 2):

With `className` you're applying a class to the element, so your CSS declaration for that class should apply.

But you're not **removing the rules applied with the ID selector #altertext**. These will **override any conflicting class rules** because the ID is a more specific selector than the class.

If you want to override rules with a class, you should set them using a different class, not an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is modify `mainfunc` and change the color, but of course @Krasimir answer is the right solution.

```
var mainfunc = function(){
    loadtext.className = "changedtext";
    loadtext.style.color = "#0F0"; 
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qzLa3/1/